# Is there a way to overlay plots from 5 different data sets in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to combine 5 plots into one so they can be compared. the x axis is "Date" and the y axis is "Cases" in all the data sets. Is there an easy way to do this. I have performed a LOESS Regression on the data, but it would be more interesting to compare the 5 sets in one plot. This is my (granted, very amateur) attempt at combining 2 of the data sets:

```
Benin<-data.frame(x=Date, y=Cases)
Togo<-data.frame(X=Date, Y=Cases)
Plot(x,y)
```

Obviously this did not work.
I am very new to r so please be gentle with me.:)

Comment: Hi Danielle, welcome to SO,  please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you corectly, you try something like this:

```
require(tidyverse)

rbind(df1 %>% 
        mutate(dataset = "one"), 
      df2 %>% 
        mutate(dataset = "two")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, cases, 
             group = dataset, 
             color = dataset)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess")
```

Result: 
[image]

Sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                 cases = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60))


df2 <- data.frame(date = c(10, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
                 cases = c(80, 90, 100, 110, 120))
```

Comment: maybe add `+ geom_smooth(method = "loess")` ?